# Sorting results returned by Yarn's REST API

Tags: rest, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I wanted to get every application that was run on the ResourceManager. I am using the REST API that comes with Yarn, specifically

```
http://<rm http address:port>/ws/v1/cluster/apps
```

This API call returns the results that I am looking for. But I would like to sort it by start time in descending order. The result that I get is not sorted in any particular order (I think it is sorted lexicographically using the application id, but I am not sure). The documentation gives a list of parameters that the API accepts but I don't see any method to sort the results. If the REST API does not support sorting, then is there any other way to sort the results?

The documentation I am following is this

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get the response in json format, you can sort it using python!

```
http://<rm http address:port>/ws/v1/cluster/apps |  python -c "import json,sys;from pprint import pprint; pprint(sorted(json.load(sys.stdin)['apps']['app'], key=lambda k: k['startedTime'], reverse=True))"|grep id
```

Comment: Well yes, I can sort it on the client side. But I was looking for something that makes the REST api return the data in a sorted way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using command line, you can use `jq`:

```
curl 'http://<rm http address:port>/ws/v1/cluster/apps' | jq '.apps.app | sort_by(-.startedTime)'
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to get the REST API return the data in a sorted way rather than having to sort data on the client side. Thanks for the help though.